# How to install Python interpreter for Microsoft VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I need a python interpreter to run some code on VS code, but I get this screen when trying to do that. Any tips to getting around this? Please let me know.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K96H.png)

I have tried using terminal to install my needs such as "pygame" but clearly that does not work unless I have python. Should I install python on my laptop then retry or is there a way to just have my interpreter in VS Code be python for virtual environments?

Comment: Welcome. Posting on Stack Overflow is a last resort for after your research efforts have failed you. For these common tasks, please try any of the tutorials you can find on [a google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=vs+code+install+python+tutorial).

Comment: VSC is a text file editor, you don't install Python for VSC, VSC uses an installed Python on the OS

Comment: Start with [Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python).

Comment: that looks to me like Visual Studio and not Visual Studio Code (they are not the same thing). Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't really have anything to do with VS Code. VS Code doesn't manage Python Installations.

You're looking at the Visual Studio Installer (note that Visual Studio and VS Code are *not* the same thing). Looks like it's got an old idea of the latest Python. If you insist on using the Visual Studio Installer to install Python, try first updating your Visual Studio Installer.

I'd suggest installing Python [from the website](https://www.python.org/downloads/), but if you're on Windows, you can also install it from the Windows Store, or from a package manager like Chocolatey.

Answer (score -1):

Vscode relies on Python existing in your system, so you must first install [Python](https://www.python.org/).

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_prerequisites) which has shown the Prerequisites:

- Python 3
- VS Code
- VS Code Python extension